# linked list, need to delete all occurences of one given integer in linked list, i am not sure where i am going wrong

Tags: java, linked-list

Find and delete all occurrences of a given info from the list. 
(Traverse the list only once.)

I can get the first number in the list to be deleted i e
if i select 1.

and the list was "1 3 4 6 7"
1 would be deleted and the count would be down by to 4 just like it supposed to be.

```
public void deleteAll(T deleteItem) {

    LinkedListNode<T> current ; // variable to traverse the list
    LinkedListNode<T> trailCurrent  ; // variable just before current
//  boolean found;



    if (first == null) // Case 1; the list is empty
        System.err.println("Cannot delete from an empty " + "list.");
    else {
        if (first.info.equals(deleteItem)) // Case 2
        {
            first = first.link;

            if (first == null) // the list had only one node
                last = null;
            count--;
        }
    else{
        trailCurrent = first;
        current = first.link;

        while(current != null){
            if(current.info.equals(deleteItem)){
            trailCurrent = current.link;
            count--;
            }
            else
                {
                    trailCurrent = current;
                    current = current.link;
                }
            }

        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you assign pointers a bit wrong when deleting elements inside collection (not first one). Try to use assignment:

```
trailCurrent.link = current.link;
```

instead of just:

```
trailCurrent = current.link;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your `while` loop's `if` clause as

```
if (current.info.equals(deleteItem)) {
  trailCurrent.link = current.link; // deletes current from list
  current = current.link; // updates current pointer
  count--;
}
```

For a set of three nodes where you want to delete node B

```
A --> B --> C
|     |
trail curr
```

*trail* should remain unchanged (point to A); *trail.link* should change from A to C i.e. *curr.link* to delete node B. In addition to that *curr* should also start pointing to C for the next iteration of `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void deleteKey(LinkedList list, int key) {
    if(list == null) {
        return;
    }

    Node temp = list.head;
    Node prev = null; 
    // If head node itself holds the key or multiple occurrences of key
    while(temp != null && temp.data == key) {
        list.head = temp.next;
        temp = list.head;
    }

    while(temp !=null) {
        if(temp.data == key) {
            prev.next = temp.next;
        } else {
            prev = temp;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}
```